# Very high fanout net not being replicated by Vivado

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I have a high fanout (~2300) write enable going into a RAM block. The RAM is distributed (hence the high fanout), and I am unable to use block RAM because of area limitations. The `fanout_limit` setting for synthesis is set to 500, but Vivado is failing to replicate this write enable accordingly.

One of my top failing timing paths is the path directly from this signal into the write enable of the RAM, and I think that reducing the fanout would alleviate a lot of the routing delay.

I get the following info message during the PhysOpt phase of Implementation:

> INFO: [Physopt 32-1022] Very high fanout net '.../d_qr_valid_in[0]' has -through timing constraint on its net segments or hierarchy pins. To preserve -through timing constraint its fanout number considered in optimization is changed from 2341 to 152 and it is not considered a very high fanout net anymore. Please consider modifying/removing the '-through' timing constraint on the net segment or hierarchy pin.

I do not understand the INFO message. I have not touched any timing constraints related to my design; the only timing constraints have been set by the vendor. This issue is internal to my design. What is actually happening here? How can I modify/remove the '-through' timing constraint as it suggests?

Comment: *" I believe I am not meeting timing because of this high fanout net."* You should generate a timing report and check the failing path(s). Then you will know if that is indeed the cause of your timing failure. Otherwise it would be a waste of timing solving a problem that does no exists.

Comment: I have updated my post to clarify. This is one of the top failing paths, and I meant that I believe the reason why is because of high fanout.

Comment: What @Oldfart suggested is really the best way you can troubleshoot Verilog/VHDL code. This is something I do at work a lot when I work with our firmware engineers. When there's a signal issue in the hardware, I ask them to generate a timing diagram of every signal that helps with the logic of another signal.

Comment: *"the only timing constraints have been set by the vendor"* have you checked if any of those a -through constraint? It might well be that you are pushing the design beyond its limits. Xilinx has all kind of tricks to deal with excessive fan-out, like replicating the register(s) where the signal originates.

Comment: I have checked the vendor constraints and cannot find "-through" anywhere. It may be true that I am pushing the design beyond its limits, but I would still like to know why Vivado refuses to replicate this particular signal when it is able to replicate others.

Comment: I have noticed this message when synthesizing a very large design. There is no user constraints related it, but I didn't found out how can Vivado see a -through constraint here.

Comment: I never did figure out the `-through` constraint, but do note that the `fanout_limit` only enforces a soft constraint on the fanout of any given net. You can force Vivado to replicate certain nets using `-force_replication_on_nets`, but be careful since it it somewhat of a hacky solution.